# Ubuntu Unity login screen from KUbuntu

Tags: unity, login, kde, screen

Is possible to use classic Ubuntu (Unity) with login screen from KUbuntu (KDE)?

Because login screen in KDE is very beautiful.

I mean this: http://static.davidedmundson.co.uk/blog/display_managers_finale/breeze_login_screen.png

Comment: You mean the background image?

Comment: No I mean http://static.davidedmundson.co.uk/blog/display_managers_finale/breeze_login_screen.png